# How to solve error "'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' Bad Data" in RSA decyption

Tags: database, winforms, encryption, rsa

I want to write a winform project using RSA algorithm for encrypting some info and save it to a database, after that (with some id, pass) take the cipher text back, do the decryption for getting the original info.

The code work fine with encryption and decryption in the same time, but get error when I take the cipher text from the database and do the decryption

```
    public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] plaintext, string destKey)
    {
        byte[] encryptedData;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(destKey);

        encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
        rsa.Dispose();
        return encryptedData;
    }

    public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] ciphertext, string srcKey)
    {
        byte[] decryptedData;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(srcKey);

        decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(ciphertext, false); //error occur here
        rsa.Dispose();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

The code take cipher text (saving on the database) and do decryption.

```
    private void btdec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = txtid.Text;
        string des = txtdes.Text;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        createConection();
        string strfind = string.Format("select detail from tb_is where id = '{0}' and description = '{1}'", id, des);
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(strfind, _con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        closeConnection();


        encryptedtext = Convert.FromBase64String(ObjectToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]));

        decryptedtex = RSADecrypt(encryptedtext, prikey);
        txtdecrypt.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedtex);           
    }
```

I have tried many different way for convert the cipher text back to the right format but it still show error bad data.

Any ideas for this problem?

Thanks.